# Will a BindingList remain a bindinglist after a .Where(..).Tolist

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-6

I'm using entity Framework 6
If a have a Bindingsource and i set Datasource like this :

```
MyBindingsource.Datasource=Context.Myobj1.Local.TobindingList
```

so MyBindingsource is bound to a bindinglist.

But what if if i set like this :

```
MyBindingsource.Datasource=Context.Myobj1.Local.TobindingList.Where(Function(t2) t2.nr>1).Tolist
```

Now MyBindingSource is bound to a bindinglist or a simple list ?

If this is a simple list , is there any way to bound to a bindinglist applying a Where() ?

Comment: `ToList<T>` is a method that returns a `List<T>`, so: simple list.

Comment: @GertArnold ok , so is there any possibility that to have my bindingsource bound to a bindinglist applying a where(....) ?

Comment: If you want a `BindingList` then create a `BindingList`. The class has a constructor that takes an `IList(Of T)`. The `ToList` method returns a `List(Of T)` and the `ToArray` method returns an array, bothin of which implement `IList(Of T)`. If you don't want the list edited, I would go with the array.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i've already tried that , but the problem is that if i bound my bindingsource to the  bindinglist created in that way , then i can't make changes to my bindingsource and after save them.